# Can a background image be larger than the qlistview item?

Tags: qt, qt4, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

I'm working on an app in which I'm using a QStandardItemModel. Every item in QstandardItemModel is a thumbnail with text. These items are bound in a QListView which are in a layout.

Is it possible to set a background for each of the QListview items such that the background is larger than the item? Or is it possible to add a frame to the item?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a frame to the item index of item, and you can set a background to each item, but I didn't understand your need to do that. I mean, if you background may be larger than item, why don't you set a whole QListView background instead?

**Edit**: How to add a frame to an item:

```
QFrame *frame = new QFrame(this);  //or any other widget-type object.
ui->listView->setIndexWidget(ui->listView->model()->index(0,0), frame); //set to desired index.
```